# Serialize/ Deserialize arbitrary Ruby objects to database

Tags: ruby, serialization, deserialization

I have a use case to store arbitrary objects (classA or classB or classC) in a column of a database table. Then when I read it, I would like to deserialize it back to the original class (A or B or C) Is it possible to do that?

It seems like I can serialize the object to json, and deserialize it to OpenStruct object. But I am hoping to get the original object so I can send it as a response which can be recognized by my protobuf definition.

[Edit]:

One extra requirement is that my server will have dependency to class A, B, C... but I have no permission to change it. Ideally I want to avoid adding extra initialize or serialize method to it.

The data stored in the database ideally could be readable after someone execute sql query. (not stored in binary format)

What I have tried is to:

1. Convert the data to hash then to json:
   a = classa_obj.to_h.to_json
2. Store it to db:

   active_record_obj.col_a = a

   active_record_obj.save
3. Retrieve the record from db:

   query_result = # sql query filter by the id
4. Covert it the json part back to class A object:

   classa_obj = ClassA.new(Json.parse(query_result.col_a))

This seems to work but I am not sure if it apply to some more complicated class structure

Comment: What have you actually tried?  Providing some code for context would be helpful Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You might want to have a look at [`Marshal`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Marshal.html) which is part of Ruby core.

Comment: @spickermann I tried to do following but got no __dump_data defined for class a. I guess it is required to define this method for customized class?                                                                                         
 o = Marshal.dump(classa_obj)
 a = Marshal.load(o)

Comment: You can use [JSON additions](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.2/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#module-JSON-label-JSON+Additions) to preserve some object characteristics of certain Ruby objects in recent Ruby versions, but JSON isn't really your best option in the general case. Also, not all objects are serializable, so without actual code examples it's impossible to advise further.

Comment: My class will be in the form of: "at most 2 ~ 3 nested levels", "each sub structure would be basic types ex: float, integer, list, map ... etc" I tested with mixed of above types in a nested class object.               
                                                                                                                 Using the way I described in the question: covert to hash then covert to json. Seems to be fine.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs Could you please suggest the ideal serialization format that could serve better than JSON in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a active record class called User and you wanted to store a class A object in a column of a User. Then you need to define that column as json type and store the data in database as hash. When you want to retrieve it you can initialize a class A object to deserialize it. Here is the code example

```
class A
  attr_reader :attr1, :attr2, :attr3

  def initialize(attr1:, attr2:, attr3:)
    @attr1 = attr1
    @attr2 = attr2
    @attr3 = attr3
  end

  def attributes
    {
      attr1: attr1,
      attr2: attr2,
      attr3: attr3
    }
  end

end
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # class_object => json type column in users table
  def class_object
    A.new(**self[:class_object])
  end
end
```

```
a = A.new(attr1: 1, attr2: 2, attr3: 3)
user = User.create(class_object: a.attributes)
user.class_object # => will return object from class A
```

Comment: Add a few extra information in the question. Is it possible to not avoid adding the initialize method to the class?

Comment: If we can't modify the classes then you need to share the class attributes, getter and setters methods(if defined) and defined methods on the class.